# Bluetooth Low Energy does it require additional hardware controller?

Tags: core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Sorry if the question is very basic.

**What I know?**

Bluetooth Low Energy is supported in the blutooth version 4.0. and it is a client server model. That is server is kind of advertiser, and client is a receiver.

**My Question.**

1) Does both the device [ client/ server] needs external hardware bluetooth chip support for BLE?

Or,

It is just enough only server to have external hardware bluetooth controller for the BLE?

2)  Why i am asking this question is that Bluetooth 4.0 is just a different implementation algorithm comparing with classic bluetooth, in all layers of the bluetooth stack, to avoid energy consumption. In that case, what is the contribution of external BLE controller?.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, both the devices needs bluetooth 4.0 chip to communicate for BLE.None of the BLE communication can happen over classic bluetooth, check wiki [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy) and [differnce](http://www.medicalelectronicsdesign.com/article/bluetooth-low-energy-vs-classic-bluetooth-choose-best-wireless-technology-your-application), BLE has low data transfer rate as compared to classic bluetooth